# How can I edit a embed message on interval?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, setinterval

```js
var dateTime = time+' '+date;

 const boosterembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("Boosters")
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setDescription("Last Time updated: " + dateTime)
            .setTimestamp()
setInterval(function(){guild.channels.get('740327839177375765').message.channel.fetchMessages('740327893103673466').edit(boosterembed)}, 1000)
```

Why is this not working? Can't add more (looks like your post is mostly code)

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: @DaemonBeast V11

Comment: Where does `time` and `date` come from?

Comment: @DaemonBeast  var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Discord.js v11.

First, `fetchMessages` is for fetching multiple messages from a channel. You'll want to use [`fetchMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) instead. Second, you use [`edit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) to edit a message. Third, a channel does not have a `message` property, so `guild.channels.get(...).message.channel` will throw an error.

```js
setInterval(
  () =>
    guild.channels.get('740327839177375765').fetchMessage('740327893103673466')
      .then(message => message.edit(boosterembed))
      // This catches all errors and logs them to stop unhandled promise rejections
      .catch(console.error),
  1000
)

// Or with async/await:
setInterval(
  async () => {
    try {
      const message = await guild.channels.get('740327839177375765').fetchMessage('740327893103673466')
      await message.edit(boosterembed)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  },
  1000
)
```

Comment: It's still not updating anything. And I had to change guild to bot.

Comment: @Hafalar436 This answer should work. Where does `boosterembed` come from? Maybe the message appears as if it's not updating because `boosterembed` doesn't change.

Comment: It's a embed message with the current time.

Comment: @Hafalar436 Please add the code for the `boosterembed` to the question.

Comment: @Hafalar436 Add the following function: `function getDate() {var today = new Date();var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear();var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();return time + ' ' + date;}` and then replace `message.edit(boosterembed)` with `message.edit(new Discord.RichEmbed(boosterembed).setDescription('Last Time updated: ' + getTime()))`.

Comment: @DaemonBeast I don't know what this is supposed to do. Or which message this is even supposed to edit.

Comment: @Hafalar436 I have posted my own answer, make sure to upvote this one though.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is adapted from cherryblossom's answer, make sure you upvote it.

```js
function getDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  return time + ' ' + date;
}

setInterval(
  () =>
    bot.channels.get('740327839177375765').fetchMessage('740327893103673466')
      .then(message => message.edit(new Discord.RichEmbed(boosterembed).setDescription('Last Time updated: ' + getTime())))
      // This catches all errors and logs them to stop unhandled promise rejections
      .catch(console.error),
  1000
)

// Or with async/await:
setInterval(
  async () => {
    try {
      const message = await bot.channels.get('740327839177375765').fetchMessage('740327893103673466')
      await message.edit(new Discord.RichEmbed(boosterembed).setDescription('Last Time updated: ' + getTime()))
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  },
  1000
)
```

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I created a message before and copied the Id but nothing happens.